Почему одна "н" в слове повинен?
Подскажите, пожалуйста, почему в кратком прилагательном "повинен" пишется одна "н", если это слово образовано от полного прилагательно повинный, где две "нн". А по правилу в кратких прил. пишется столько н, сколько в полных

Повинный —  повинна —  повинны —  повинЕн, беглая гласная Е для прилаг. м.р.  между двумя НН. Объяснение можно посмотреть  https://oross.ruslang.ru/orthogr/formula?id=194 (Не знаю, что за ресурс, первый раз вижу.)  Про беглую гласную и так ясно.

@Sharon забавно, хотя вроде при поддержке президентского фонда создан сайт)

Президентский? А я подумала: самодеятельность, что ли, какая?  Как-то не впечатлилась их толкованиями. У классиков наших (в правилах) сказано, что НН сохраняется, кроме прилаг.  мужского рода. Не посчитали нужным давать более подробные объяснения.

Ну во-первыхъ это краткое причастіе, какъ разбирается оно думаю вы знаете, но напомню: по-вин-ен-ъ, гдѣ по- приставка, вин- корень, -ен страдательнаго причастія суффиксъ, -ъ окончаніе. Соотвѣтственно, если причастіе образуется отъ глагола, то достаточно просто приставить къ корню суффиксъ, мѣна же н/нн возникаетъ на фонѣ полныхъ причастій: повинный или повинённый по стандартнымъ правиламъ :)

Это ничего, что повинен —  краткое прилагательное, а не причастие? https://morfologicheskij-razbor.ru/imya-prilagatelnoe/повинный
